# Joins in nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, join, queryover

I am using blow code for join in nhibernate, which is working fine. But i don't wants to use `.List` on both queries before join, i wants to use `.List`  after join. I don't know nhibernate too much.. please provide me help that what i should make changes in below funciton to first join the data and then apply `.List` over it.

```
 public IEnumerable<PGrp> GetSol()
    {
        _pGrpR = null;
        _pGrp = null;

        QueryOver<Phy, Phy> activePhyQuery = GetDataQuery();

        var phyGrpR = _session.QueryOver(() => _pGrpR)
        .Where(
            Subqueries.WhereProperty<PGrpR>(p => _pGrpR.PhyId).In(
                activePhyQuery))
        .List<PGrpR>();

        IList<PGrp> pGrps = _session.QueryOver(() => _pGrp)
            .Where(x => !x.AC)
            .List<PGrp>();

        var newPGrps = pGrps
            .Join(
                pGrpR,
                p => p.Id,
                x => x.PGrpId,
                (p, x) => p
            ).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.Name);

        return newPGrps;
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 PGrpR pGrpR = null;
 IList<PGrp> pGrps = _session.QueryOver(() => _pGrp)
            .Where(x => !x.AC)
            .JoinAlias(pgrps => pgrps.pGrpR, () => pGrpR) // Set real property name
            .OrderBy(() => pGrpR.Name).Asc
            .Select(Projections.Distinct(Projections.Property(() => pGrpR."PropertyForDistinct")))
            .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
            .List<PGrp>();
```